# How to add custom webparts to pages in powershell scripts?

Tags: sharepoint, scripting, powershell

I have created a custom webpart and added to the webpart gallery.I need to add that webpart control in my page.
Please help me how to achieve this in powershell scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Use [GetLimitedWebPartsManager()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlimitedwebpartmanager.aspx) to obtain a reference to your page's manager, then call its [AddWebPart()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms416766.aspx) method:

```
$mgr = $web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($yourPageUrl,
    [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared)
$mgr.AddWebPart($yourWebPart, "YourZone", 0);
```

See http://blogs.flexnetconsult.co.uk/colinbyrne/2007/02/10/SharePointPowerShell8TheOneWithTheContactWebPart.aspx for a detailed example.

Comment: How would set `$yourWebPart` in this example?

Comment: Well, you would instantiate your web part class. For instance, the example in the link above issues `$webpart=new-object  Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.ContactFieldControl`.

Comment: How would you reference a custom web part class (something not built into Microsoft)?  If it's in the GAC, would it be possible to just do something like {AssemblyName}.{ClassName}?

Comment: I never encountered any problem with fully-qualified names to GACed assemblies, and `Microsoft.Sharepoint.*` is not actually built in Microsoft systems (it's a additional component). Do you have problems referencing your web part class this way?

Comment: Yeah, I've been having some trouble.  You can see a more detailed explanation here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25267/how-to-add-an-instance-of-a-custom-webpart-to-a-web-page-using-powershell/25269#25269

Answer (score 0):

### Here is simple script to add a webpart to apage using powershell Which is Tested and working fine

#### http://soreddymanjunath.blogspot.in/2014/07/add-webpart-to-page-using-powershell.html

Please note that to add a webpart to a page export webpart to your local drive and .webpart/.dwp file will in xml format

```
cls

asnp "*sh*"

$web=Get-SPweb -Identity "http://SP2013dev.com/sites/addwebpart/"

[xml]$webpartxml= Get-Content -Path "C:\Manju\WPRequest.xml"

$SR = New-Object System.IO.StringReader($webpartxml.OuterXml)

$XTR = New-Object System.Xml.XmlTextReader($SR)

$err=$null

$WebPartZoneID = "Topzone"

$WebPartZoneIndex = 0

 try
   {

  $page=$web.GetFile("Pages/default.aspx");

  $bool=$page.CheckedOutBy

        if($bool)
        {
            Write-Host "Page is already Checkout to " $page.CheckedOutBy.UserLogin

            $page.UndoCheckOut()

            Write-Host "Page is Over ridded by " $web.CurrentUser.DisplayName + " to Add Webpart"
        }

    $page.CheckOut();

    $wmgr=$web.GetLimitedWebPartManager($page,    [System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope]::Shared);

    $webpart=$wmgr.ImportWebPart($XTR,[ref]$err);

    $wmgr.AddWebPart($webpart,$WebPartZoneID,$WebPartZoneIndex);

    $page.CheckIn('dude');

    $page.Publish('Adding request Site Webpart') 

    "Request Site WebPart SucessfullAdded" + (Get-Date -DisplayHint Date) | Out-File -Append "C:\OutPutLog.txt" 

     $SR.Close();
     $XTR.Close();
     $web.Dispose()

    }
    catch
    {
        $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message 

        "Request Site WebPart Failure" + $ErrorMessage  +  (Get-Date -DisplayHint Date) | Out-File -Append "C:\ErrorLog.txt"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on our requirements, but we could use JavaScript or other Client Object Model libraries to add a web part to SharePoint page. My advice is, even if your requirements guide you to write PowerShell script, try to use Client Object Model instead Server Object Model, whenever possible.

If you want to add directly from XML variable take care about this line:

Import the webpart

$wp = $webpartManager.ImportWebPart($WebPartXml.OuterXml)

You can see more information here: http://josharepoint.com/2016/02/16/using-powershell-to-add-webpart-to-sharepoint-page-via-csom-in-office-365/